# How to I unlock the Comedy Specs?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-5-7

How do I unlock the Comedy Specs in Lego Harry Potter years 5-7? Is it in the Weasley shop?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Lego Game Blog,](https://legogamehelp.wordpress.com/2014/06/18/red-brick-guide/) the Comedy Specs are already unlocked when you start the game, and just need to be purchased in the Leaky Cauldron.